# Blade Tag Condition in one line Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

i have a code that show if condition in my blade like this

```
@if($user->status == "Y")
     <span class="badge bg-success">Active</span>
@else
     <span class="badge bg-danger">Not Active</span>
@endif
```

And i want it show in one line This if condition like this:

```
{{ $user->status ? Active : Not Active }}
```

but it doesn't work with html span tag in it

I tried this code

```
{{ $user->status ?echo "<span class="badge bg-success">Active</span>" : echo "<span class="badge bg-danger">Not Active</span>" }}
```

And still it doesn't work

Comment: Your new check is assuming status is a boolean, and in your first check status is a string with a certain value. (`$user->status == "Y"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply put into where you want to rendered.

```php
<span class="badge bg-{{ $user->status ? 'success' : 'danger' }}">{{ $user->status ? 'Active' : 'Not Active' }}</span>
```